# XML×files left out of solution but in source control c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have a solution for a web service harness used to create sample XML templates. We recently merged the solution into another branch. All the of the XML template files are left out of the solution when it's opened, however they appear in source control as being there. The menus of the application are created dynamically based on the name of each XML file. Even with the XML files added to the solution after, the menus are still not created. Before we merged branches it worked flawlessly. Does anyone have any idea what would cause this / how to include XML files into the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the solution explorer, select the project that should contain the xml files. If they are already added you can skip this. Otherwise click the Icon in the top which says `Show alla files` and right click on each xml file and choose `Include in project`. Choose properties for each xml file and choose `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to output location: Always`

Comment: Turns out I needed to change the build action to "Embedded Resources" and not "Content" which it was set to. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, files included in your visual studio solution and files in your source control depot are independent concepts.  You can have files that are included in the solution but not in source control, or vise-versa.  You say your menus are created by reading contents of some XML files and that is no longer working.  Chances are your xml files are not at the place where your code expects them to be.  Try running the menu loading code in the debugger and see where your code is looking for the xml files.